# How to add condition in 'order by'?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure with an input parameter, Now on the basis of this parameter my 'order by' statement will change like if input parameter is 'ID'(int type column) then order by ID, if it is 'ProductType' then order by Producttype and if it is 'IssueDate' then it should be order by issueDate.

right now i have added 2 if else statement in my SP, but this solution is not scalable so my question is there any better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using SQL Server you can use a case statement

```
order by
    case inputparameter
    when 'id'  then id
    when 'productType' then ProductType
    else  defaultOrderBy
    end
```